# Error on download file path in mvc controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

This is my actionlink on the index view.

```css
@Html.ActionLink("Download File", "Download", new { fileName = Model.OriginalRecordRelativeFilePath })


public FileResult Download(string fileName)
{
     try
     {
          var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationHelper.IntegrationInterfaceFolderPath + fileName));
     // ConfigurationHelper.IntegrationFolderPath is a path for C:\Data\IntergrationInterface\

     return File(fs, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
 }
 catch
 {
      throw new HttpException(404, "Couldn't find " + fileName);
 }
```

}

I try to download the file from C:\Data\IntergrationInterface\fileName. But it cannot find the path of C:\Data\IntergrationInterface\fileName and throw exception (Couldnt find fileName). May i know is there any ways to download the file from local c while running localhost web service on the same computer? Thank you.

Comment: The exception doesn't lie. Does the file exist? Verify the path, preferably by storing it in a separate variable. Does the user this site runs as have permissions to read the file?

Comment: Yes. The file existed. I created a dummy file named path in C:\Data\IntergrationInterface\path. the user this site is coded as system admin. So it has permission to read the file.

Comment: Change the code to `string path = ConfigurationHelper.IntegrationInterfaceFolderPath + fileName; path = Server.MapPath(path); var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);`. Inspect the variables on each step.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use Server.MapPath here instead use your file path directly. For example @"C:\Data\IntergrationInterface\".

Currently you are trying to do Server.MapPath(@"C:\Data\IntergrationInterface\file.txt"), it means you are giving a physical path where as MapPath method expects a virtual path. Instead of this if you would give Server.MapPath("\ABC") then it will return the server path as "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ABC", which will be basically your local server path.